# Вывод переменной php в колонку таблицы html

Tags: php, html, table

Есть переменная `php` которую нужно вывести на страницу html в конкретную колонку таблицы. Подскажите пожалуйста как это сделать.
`$user = $_POST['user'];`в колонку c id `user`
`$time = date('H:i:s');` в колонку с id `time`

```css
table#messages {
  width: 490px;
  height: 260px;
  background: #fffecd;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<table id="messages">
  <col id="time" valign="top">
  <col id="name" valign="top">
  <tr>
    <td id="time"></td>
    <td id="name"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: <td id="time"><?=$user?></td>

Answer (score 1):

```
<table id="messages">
  <col id="time" valign="top">
  <col id="name" valign="top">
  <tr>
    <td id="time"><?=date('H:i:s')?></td>
    <td id="name"><?=htmlspecialchars($_POST['user'])?></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

(Конструкция `<?=$var?>` работает [даже когда отключены короткие теги](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php))